# lightning:buttonMenu - menu layover issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-buttonmenu

I've created a lightning component which has a menu and this is how it opens:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it ?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to add z-index with !important but it doesn't work.
I realized it's not possible to override css.
Does someone have a workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to apply the `z-index` CSS property for your dropdown menu, which sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one. [z-index (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work